# Nginx - proxy_pass - specific location not working

Tags: nginx, rewrite, proxypass

I am trying to masking a remote URL with Nginx using proxy_pass

I'd like to load *staging.saas.localhost/_* when the browser url is *saas.localhost/uk_staging*.

For some reason the location in **saas.localhost** is not working, and for not working I mean that the location seems to be ignored.

**saas.localhost/uk_staging** is handled by the application and not from **staging.saas.localhost/_**, it seems to me that even for **saas.localhost/uk_staging** the location used is location ~ .php$

I created a 2nd domain **t.saas.localhost** and it is working as expected

The **t.saas.localhost** domain is working perfectly fine.

**t.saas.localhost/uk_staging** is displaying **staging.saas.localhost/_**
**t.saas.localhost/anything_else** is displaying **google.co.uk/**

This is my current Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   saas.localhost www.saas.localhost staging.saas.localhost;
    root /codebase/saas;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /uk_staging {
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://staging.saas.localhost/_;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  t.saas.localhost;
    root /codebase/saas;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location /uk_staging {
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://staging.saas.localhost/_;
    }
    location / {
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://google.co.uk;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you do a proxy pass to you own servername ?

Comment: Mhn, I don't think because if it were the case it should not work the t.saas.localhost as well. 
I configured all the host files 
Nginx seems ignoring the location in the 'location: /uk_staging' of the first configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you redirecting to the same vhost with a `proxy_pass` directive ?!

Also, nginx elects the matching location a way you probably don't expect.
Read this : [Nginx rewite rules 403 error](https://serverfault.com/questions/629406/nginx-rewite-rules-403-error/629619#629619).

It's better not to use `if` when it's possible to avoid it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   saas.localhost www.saas.localhost staging.saas.localhost;
    root /codebase/saas;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ^~ /uk_staging {
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://staging.saas.localhost/_; # What are you doing here ??!!
    }

    #avoid rewrite for static content
    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css|htm|html|gif|txt|swf|mpg|mp4|avi)$ {
            expires 30d;
    }


    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ proxy_pass http://staging.saas.localhost/_; # What are you doing here ??!!

I trying to load the page: http://staging.saas.localhost/_, it's an actual page

Comment: "Why are you redirecting to the same vhost with a proxy_pass directive ?!"
Because 'staging.saas.localhost' is the staging environment whilst 'saas.localhost' is the live one. 

Everything is handled by the app, but I'd like to mask http://staging.saas.localhost/_ with http://saas.localhost/uk_staging

Comment: @Jeff Do you realize they are served by the same server block ? I really don't follow your logic. Also, you are adding duplicate content in your production environment in order to serve a staging one ?? Maybe you need to post the whole configuration to make it clear because for what I see atm it's seems a huge mess for nothing.

Comment: I think that make a bucle, for the same reaseon the second option (t.saas.localhost) work well for you

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked with a little tweak:

location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css|htm|html|gif|txt|swf|mpg|mp4|avi)$ {
                expires 30d;
}

to not rewrite static resources with 
location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 last;
}