# simple nginx alias not working while trying to serve files other than document root

Tags: nginx, alias

i am trying to serve images which are stored in different location other than document root.

```
#avatar files block
location ~^/pics/profile/(.*)$ {
        alias   /home/data/site_data/profile/$1;
}
```

i have added above code block in the `nginx .conf` file and did

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

and when i tried to access

```
http://www.example.com/pics/profile/1/1.jpg
```

it gives me **404 not found error**.

how can i fix this ?
i have specified document root  at the top of `nginx configuration` file like this

```
root   /usr/share/nginx/site.com/html;
```

i have checked and the file exists at

```
/home/data/site_data/profile/1/1.jpg
```

update :

my full config is like this

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;
        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 6M;

root   /home/data/nginx/example.com/html;

location / {
        index  index.php index.html;
}

#error_page  403 404 500 502 503 504             /404.html;

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

access_log  /dev/null;

#restrict php execution from these directories
location ^~ /cache/ {location ~* \.php$ { return 404; }}
location ^~ /content/ {location ~* \.php$ { return 404; }}
location ^~ /css/ {location ~* \.php$ { return 404; }}
location ^~ /images/ {location ~* \.php$ { return 404; }}
location ^~ /js/ {location ~* \.php$ { return 404; }}
location ^~ /pics/ {location ~* \.php$ { return 404; }}


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.(php)$ {
        try_files       $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        }


#avatar files block
location ~^/pics/profile/(.*)$ {
        alias   /home/data/site_data/profile/$1;
}


include /etc/nginx/example.com_rewrite_rules.conf;
}
```

Comment: Show full config

Comment: @AlexeyTen updated with full config file

Comment: `location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$` matches request so it never get to your "avatar" `location`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen i commented out those lines, restarted nginx and still getting 404 thanks

Comment: Read the answer here http://serverfault.com/questions/629406/nginx-rewite-rules-403-error/629619#629619 specifically the section under the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` block you use works like this:

The url `http://your-site.com/pics/profile/pic.jpg` is served from `/home/data/site_data/profile/pic.jpg/pic.jpg`.

This is because `alias` refers to the directory where the file is served from.

If you want to serve `/home/data/site_data/profile/pic.jpg` on that URL, you can use this location block:

```
location /pics/profile {
    alias /home/data/site_data/profile;
}
```

Also, I would use a location like this for PHP execution prevention:

```
location ^~ ^/(cache|content|css|images|js|pics)/.+\.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: location pics/profile is working but PHP execution prevention block isnt working., anyways thanks for your input.

Comment: I had one extra `^` inside the `location` regex for PHP, it should work now.

Comment: still able to execute php inside cache. anyways thats not the issue, here , i would like to ask , is there more work for os if nginx had to rewrite something which is not available under public html ? like what i am trying to achieve ?

Comment: Well, all extra rewrites add some load to the server, but it is not much at all, so one doesn't really need to care about that, except for really busy sites. I am just perfectionist..